# selenium firefox webdriver triggers uninstaller helper.exe to open

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

OS: Windows 7
Firefox: 37
Selenium-java: 2.45.0

I am able to control firefox with code using selenium library. However, for some reason, besides opening the firefox browser, it always opens firefox unsinstaller (helper.exe) as well, with the message "Installer corrupted: invalid opcode".

Does any one know why firefox uninstaller is even triggered in the first place?

thanks

Comment: Does it happen if you open firefox in a usual way directly? Also, does downgrading to Firefox 35 help?

Comment: if I open firefox the usual way (double clicking icon), it fires up as usual (no uninstaller popping up).   I have not tried Firefox 35 though. I was initially using 38.0.1 but it didn't work. After reading this thread [https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/437], I then switched 37.